# Converting the SSD drive to GPT only by diskpart without formatting the HDD

Tags: windows, partitioning, ssd

I'm trying to clean install Windows 10,
I have an SSD and HDD, SSD is where I install Windows,
When I prompted that I can't install Windows on the SSD drive because it's in MBR format and it needs to be converted to GPT, I found the solution (https://youtu.be/pb6tECZP6WE) is to format the drive.
but I'm afraid that this will also format the HDD (this happened to me in the past, but with a laptop with HDD only, all drives have been formatted)

I want to run `clean` command to only the SSD drive

This is on the screen now
[image]

Should I proceed? (only the SSD drive (disk 1) will be formated without affecting the other disks

Comment: I removed the HDD from the laptop and installed windows on the SSD, after installation finished the HDD isn't listed on windows!

Comment: Solved : from disk management >Actions>rescan disks..